# primitive type double error

Tags: java, compareto

sorry if my question looks very stupid. I get error on .compareTo() Cannot invoke compareTo(double) on the primitive type double! how can i fix this ? Thank you!

Vehicle class:

```
public class Vehicle implements IOutput {
private double cost;}

public double getCost(){
        return cost;
    }
```

Array Class:

```
public static void sortByVehicleMakeModel(Vehicle[] vehicles) {

    boolean swapped = true;

    for(int y = 0; y < vehicles.length && swapped; y++) {
        swapped=false;
        for(int x = 0; x < vehicles.length - (y+1); x++) {
            if(vehicles[x].getCost().compareTo(vehicles[x + 1].getCost()) > 0){
                swap(vehicles, x, x + 1);
                swapped=true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my other codes works fine:

```
public static void sortByOwnerName(Vehicle[] vehicles) {
    boolean swapped = true;

    for(int y = 0; y < vehicles.length && swapped; y++) {
        swapped=false;
        for(int x = 0; x < vehicles.length - (y + 1); x++) {
            if(vehicles[x].getOwner().getName().compareTo(vehicles[x + 1].getOwner().getName())> 0) {   
                swap(vehicles, x, x + 1);
                swapped=true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does `getCost()` return a `double` or a `Double`? From the error message, I think `Double` and the problem is lack of a `>0`. But let's double-check!

Comment: @AndrewLazarus: The error message says - "... Cannot invoke compareTo(double) **on the primitive type double**".

Comment: Stupid question, and off-topic, but why are you doing a bubble-sort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the return type of your `getCost()` method from `double` to `Double` and it will all work. Auto boxing will take care of the rest.

Comment: This will NOT work because there's no comparison operator (==, >, <)! It's not C++ with an implicit test against 0.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus: Please care to read the answer carefully before going around just downvoting carelessly.

Comment: @BheshGurung Well, all of you missed the real error, so you get downvoted. Truth is, I don't do that so often, but this was egregious. If getCost() is returning a `double`, the correct solution isn't boxing both sides (extremely slow operation), but using a vanilla comparison statement.

Comment: I wouldn't just blindly call it an extremely slow operation (specially without knowing the real context). Also, I don't see anybody talking about performance here. I think it's pretty clear that the OP is trying to invoke that `compareTo` method.

Comment: @BheshGurung. Is he trying to invoke it because he forgot getCost() returns a double? Because he just copy/pasted from the other field? If it's a primitive, then compareTo is overkill. It might be that the compiler sees the boxing/unboxing is a waste and optimizes it out. If not, it's slow, given that the basic question is a simple compare-and-branch.

Comment: I changed this to :     public Double getCost() in stead of                                          public double getCost(){
        return cost;
    }

Comment: @Niloo The difference is double is a primitive type, which have no methods, but Double is an object thats  a very thin wrapper around a primitive double value which allows the primitive to be used as an object and provides some methods. And the "boxing" process is extremely fast... the other guy who said it was slow doesn't know what he's talking about.

Answer (score 1):

`if(vehicles[x].getCost().compareTo(vehicles[x + 1].getCost()))`

You need `>0` in there somewhere!

Comment: if(vehicles[x].getCost().compareTo(vehicles[x + 1].getCost()) > 0){ didn't work and same error!!

Comment: In that case, you have TWO errors. If getCost returns a `double` (small d), don't use compareTo. Just use plain old `if (a.getCost() > b.getCost())` If it returns a `Double`, compareTo should work and you have a typo somewhere. [If you want, you can use the `Double` stuff on `getCost()` which returns a `double`, but that is _very_ inefficient.]

Comment: wow Andrew, I learned a lot from you Thank you!  :D ... & I had NO what so ever Idea that a d or D can make a big difference ;)

Answer (score 1):

`compareTo` method is not available on premitive type. Use `Wrapper Double` as:

```
     if(Double.valueOf(vehicles[x].getCost())
          .compareTo(Double.valueOf(vehicles[x + 1].getCost()))>0){
```

Please Note: [**Double.valueOf(double)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28double%29) returns the Wrapper type `Double` with value as `double`.

**Please Note:** If your objective is to use `compareTo` then its fine otherwise, you may want to directly compare `double` values using comparison operators `<, >, ==` as appropriate.

Comment: This will NOT work because there's no comparison operator (==, >=, <=)! It's not C++ with an implicit test against 0.

Comment: I tried but said : Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean

Comment: Look at the line that works. You see how it has a test `> 0`? Now look at the line that fails. No test. And don't test against `true` or `false`; compareTo returns an int. Compare against 0-.

Comment: @Niloo: I updated the answer. Also I validated it it. It works for `double` values.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus: It was silly ignorance. Corrected the answer.

Comment: Undid the -1. However, rather than doing all that boxing, `if (a.getCost()>b.getCost())` will be much faster.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus: True. I tried making `compareTo` work. I will add this note as well.

Comment: @YogendraSingh: Well, the original poster still hasn't said whether getCost() returns d or D. So the best fix partly depends on that.

Comment: @Andrew Lazarus this works fine but it was required to use .CommpareTo :(

Comment: @AndrewLazarus If `getCost()` would have returning `D` then it would not have been failing with mentioned error.

Answer (score 0):

You can only invoke methods on a reference type, `double` is a primitive type. As the error message suggests `vehicles[x].getCost()` returns a `double`.

One thing you can do is manually box your `double` into `Double`:

```
int costComp = Double.valueOf(vehicles[x].getCost()).compareTo(Double.valueOf(vehicles[x + 1].getCost());

if(costComp < 0) {
    //...
} else if(costComp == 0) {
    //...
} else {
    //...
}
```

Comment: This will NOT work because there's no comparison operator (==, >=, <=)! It's not C++ with an implicit test against 0.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus: I don't know on what basis you were saying what will not work.

Answer (score 0):

This code of yours works fine

`if(vehicles[x].getOwner().getName().compareTo(vehicles[x+1].getOwner().getName())> 0)`

because `vehicles[x+1].getOwner().getName()` must be returning an object of `String` and `compareTo` method accepts an object as an argument.

This code doesn't work

`if(vehicles[x].getCost().compareTo(vehicles[x + 1].getCost()))`

because `vehicles[x + 1].getCost()` must not be returning an object( in your case it must be returning a primitive `double` ) so there is mismatch in the type and the compiler complains that there is no such `compareTo` method that accepts `double` (a primitive)

Comment: @Niloo is your `vehicles[x + 1].getCost()` returns an object of type `Double`?

Answer (score 0):

I changed this to :

```
public Double getCost()
```

instead of

```
public double getCost(){ 
return cost; 
}
```

Comment: Because the little-d double **is not an object,** so you can't call methods on it. If you could, you could write `4.3.compareTo(-11.8);` So you did have TWO errors, one about using boxes, and one about comparing to zero. Personally, I would revert to returning a double and _not_ using compareTo; you incur needless overhead this way.

Comment: @Andrew thank you, but it was required by my professor. Sorry for trouble ,but I learned a lot :)